# How do I manipulate elements in a numpy array with a boolean array?

Tags: python, numpy

For instance, if I have

```
true_false = np.array([[True, False], [True, False]])
to_change = np.array([[10, 10], [10, 10]])
```

and I want to multiply the values in `to_change` that are True in the `true_false` array by `20`, how would I do this without iterating through to_change?

I tried doing this by iterating through to_change and then indexing true_false which worked but I would like to do this faster without iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
to_change[true_false] *= 20
```

Updated `to_change`:

```
array([[200,  10],
       [200,  10]])
```